# Parse.query lessThanOrEqualTo doesn't work with date

Tags: parse-platform

I'm trying to select a range of data with this code.

```
var dateStart = new Date(2016, 5, 5);
var dateEnd = new Date(2016, 9, 5);
$query.greaterThanOrEqualTo("createdAt", dateStart);
$query.lessThanOrEqualTo("createdAt", dateEnd);
```

That is returning data of all month 9 and not until day 5. 
why is this happening?

Comment: Returns: lessThanOrEqualTo - 
createdAt:"2016-09-27T13:21:36.318Z"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var dateStart = new Date(2016, 4, 5);
var dateEnd = new Date(2016, 9, 5);
```

Months starts in 0, so I had to use 4 to May and 9 to October.